# SQL Server LocalDB accessed by client via EF and Windows service

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a Windows C# WPF client application where I use EF to access a LocalDB instance (of course this will be later a real SQL Server database). This application uses the database to persist some configurations. The database will be created initially by EF using the CreateDatabaseIfNotExists initializer.

Then there is a Windows service running with Local System privileges automatically on startup. This service accesses the database only on startup to fetch one specific configuration value using the following code (removed exception handling from sample code, no EF used as you can see):

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection
{
    ConnectionString = $"Data Source =(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=D:\database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30",
})
{
    connection.Open();
    string query = "SELECT TOP 1 COLUMN_1 FROM TABLE_1;";

    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (!reader.IsDBNull(0))
            {
                value = reader.GetString(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've tested this code snippet many times and set debug breakpoints at f.e. the while-loop but the client application could always start and had no problems with the database creation (because it does already exist).

The problem is that "it works on my machine" doesn't satisfy the test people because they get sometimes an error that after a restart the database cannot be created anymore. This is the exception stacktrace:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot create file 'D:\database.mdf' because it already exists. Change the file path or the file name, and retry the operation.
>   CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors.
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action wrapCloseInAction)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action wrapCloseInAction)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
>      at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.b__0(DbCommand t, DbCommandInterceptionContext c)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action executing, Action executed)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.NonQuery(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
>      at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.<>c__DisplayClass1a.b__19(DbConnection conn)
>      at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.<>c__DisplayClass33.b__32()
>      at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0()
>      at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func operation)
>      at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action operation)
>      at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingConnection(DbConnection sqlConnection, Action act)
>      at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingMasterConnection(DbConnection sqlConnection, Action act)
>      at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.CreateDatabaseFromScript(Nullable commandTimeout, DbConnection sqlConnection, String createDatabaseScript)
>      at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.DbCreateDatabase(DbConnection connection, Nullable commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection storeItemCollection)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateDatabase(DbConnection connection, Nullable commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection storeItemCollection)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.CreateDatabase()
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.DatabaseOperations.Create(ObjectContext objectContext)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.DatabaseCreator.CreateDatabase(InternalContext internalContext, Func createMigrator, ObjectContext objectContext)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.CreateDatabase(ObjectContext objectContext, DatabaseExistenceState existenceState)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Database.Create(DatabaseExistenceState existenceState)
>      at System.Data.Entity.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists.InitializeDatabase(TContext context)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.<>c__DisplayClassf`1.b__e()
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization()
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.b__4(InternalContext c)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction.PerformAction(TInput input)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action action)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase()
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet.Initialize()
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet.get_InternalContext()
>      at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
>      bei System.Linq.Queryable.Count[TSource](IQueryable source)
>      bei MyProgram.DatabaseService.Initialize()

I cannot explain myself what goes wrong.

Maybe there are model mismatches or race conditions but I cannot get the scenario to reproduce this error and to be honest the error message looks so simple.

**EDIT:**

After checking the file handles with procmon you can see that the service "blocks" the database file as long as it uses it plus some extra time (maybe this time is needed by SQLLocalDB itself).
In this time no other user can access the database. I tried the same with a client and a service running as the same user and then both could access the file concurrently. How can this be?

Comment: I'm guessing you are creating the database using code-first. I had some similar issues after deleting the migration histories in the project but forgot to do so in the database. Might this be the case? just a thought, hope it helps.

Comment: Yes I am using code first. Can you explain me your solution?

Comment: well, like I said, make sure your migration folder from your project matches the migration history table in the database. One of them might be missing one or more entries. The easiest way to overpass this is by just deleting the migration folder from the project and the migration table in the database and re-enabling migrations again. You only need the migrations in development mode anyway so it shouldn't be such a big problem if you'll loose the old ones and move the initial state of the database to the state it's in now.

Comment: I'm sorry but I have no migrations folder or doesn't know where to find it. When I search for how to disable data migrations I can't find a good explanation

Comment: well, if you enabled migrations for your project, in the same project where your data entities are you should have a folder called Migrations, and in your database you should have the following table: __MigrationHistory. If you didn't enabled migrations then you need to go trough the following steps to do it: Go to Tools > Nuget Packet Manager > Packet Manager Console (make sure you did it while you were in he same project as your entities), and run the following lines: enable-migrations - next one is: add-migration - this will ask you for a name, let's say: Initial, next -> update-database.

Comment: I suggest you learning more about entity framework code-first and migrations since there are a few options that you can set up depending on how you want to persist the changes to the database and so on.. you can start here: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/entity-framework-code-first.aspx

Comment: p.s., you do not want to disable it, you need that to persist any changes in your model to the database.